# AS3 safe downloaded file directly to specified folder

Tags: file, actionscript-3, dialog, skip, download

May be some body have FLA file which download file to folder (without dialog of save file).

Just Click to - DOWNLOAD -> file save to folder /update on swf located. (without any confirmation of filename or filder location)

```
       var fileName:String = "upgrade.zip";
       var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
       request.url = DOWNLOAD_URL;
       var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
       fr.download(request,fileName);
```

This change filename in dialog only, but dialog must to be auto-agreed.

And more one. When I try to make AS3 script, for download via URLRequest, this work only in Flash editor. FLA file (when I comp[ile to SWF -> not work).

Comment: You can't download file “without dialog of save file” in AS3.

Comment: I shure can be other way (ByteArray read then save to file)

Comment: Do you use Adobe AIR or FlashPlayer?

Comment: If it's AIR you can do it using FileStream, if it's not AIR you can't do it without user getting a confirm window.

Comment: It won't work with Flash Web because that would be a massive security issue. Think about it, would you like some random flash movie download some kind of nonsense on your PC without you knowing? But like BotMaster said, with AIR applications it will work.

Comment: Mans!!! PLEASE!!!! I need work solution!!!! Achtung!!!

Comment: Also, may be have some solution to make this application runnable from PDF manual, now work only from  Adobe Flash

Comment: We told you the solution. You can't even answer if your application is Web or AIR, so what else are we supposed to tell you?